# Using SED Editing single xml element and splitting into two?

Tags: xml, sed

I've currently got the following xml but have trouble processing as date and time contained within a single element.

```
<data>
    <StartDateTime>2019-10-19T12:00:00Z</StartDateTime>
</data>
```

but want it output as:

```
<data>
   <date>2019-10-19</date>
   <time>12:00:00Z</time>
</data>
```

Is it possible using sed to alter this?

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Answer (score 1):

@Cyrus is right when he says that [[X]HTML cannot be parsed with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

But if you are sure the input will always look like this, and since the input isn't as complex, you can, in fact, do it with sed:

```
sed -E 's|<StartDateTime>([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[A-Z])</StartDateTime>|<date>\1</date>\n    <time>\2</time>|g'
```

This expression uses capturing groups which you can later [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html) in the substitution with `'\'` followed by the index of the group, `\1` and `\2` in this case.